# How to disable div tag in asp button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

Button click div tag is disabled but after page load again enable. How to stay disable after page load in button click

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function toggledisable() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById('flip').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('flip1').style.display = "none";
        });  

    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can use Cookies, ViewState, Session or Database. To store the status of the toggle.

Answer (score 0):

You just changed the `display` in client side but the `ViewState` of control is not updated. You can keep the changed state in hidden field and use those `hidden` field no server side to show or hide `div`.

Also remove document.ready from toggledisable()

*HTML*

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnflip" />
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnflip1" />
```

*Javascript*

```
function toggledisable() {      
    document.getElementById('<%= flip.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('<%= flip1.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";  
    document.getElementById('<%= hdnflip.ClientID %>').value = "true";       
    document.getElementById('<%= hdnflip1.ClientID %>').value = "true";       
}
```

*Code behind*

```
flip.Visible = bool.Parse(hdnflip.Value)      
flip1.Visible = bool.Parse(hdnflip1.Value)
```

Comment: With out using Runat="Server". I have used toggle button so if i added runat then toggle is not working.